# Pagination Not Working on custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have created a Custom Post type and its page template, i want pagination on my custom post type page template

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

    $qry = array(
                 'post_type' => 'property',
                 'posts_per_page' => '3',
                 'oerder' => 'ASC',
                 'page' => $paged,
        );

    $listing = new WP_Query($qry);

    if($listing->have_posts()):
        while($listing->have_posts()):
            $listing->the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

I am using page_navi Plugin for pagination but its not working,
I am also using the wordpress pagination , here is the code

```
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php get_next_posts_link(); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php get_previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
```

but its also not working.
Please Suggest me some Solutions ASAP 
Thanks

Comment: What does it mean “not working”?

Comment: Div is showing of previous and next post in inspecting element,
but not showing on the page

Comment: your `order` is not spelled correctly...

Comment: ALSO http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query

Comment: I have made the spell of order correct but this also doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

So that I can just submit this and have you look into this a little easier with some explanation.

It is not `page` for pagination in Wordpress. It is `paged`.

So your query should be....

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // changed all page to paged

$qry = array(
          'post_type' => 'property',
          'posts_per_page' => '3',
          'order' => 'ASC', // This was spelled wrong...
          'paged' => $paged, // changed page to paged
        );
```

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query for full documentation on how to set the paged variable and use it correctly.

Your order was spelled incorrectly and as that is just above paged it could potentially mess something up, but highly doubtful. I would correct it for the expected execution.

Answer (score 1):

Here gallery is custom post type.

```
function get_all_gallery_posts( $query ) {
        if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'gallery' ) ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '6' );
        }
    }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_all_gallery_posts' );
```